# Cypress: Check list of hrefs, assert they do NOT contain a certain string

Tags: iteration, cypress, href, assertion

I have a list of hrefs that I need to check. I only need to make sure that none of them contains the string "creditcheck"

The html looks like this:

```html
<div class="yiiTab clearfix content-right-side" id="clientinfotabs">
    <ul class="tabs left-side-tabs">
        <li>
            <a reloadonclick="" loadurl="/index.php?r=foo/bar;id=12345&amp;language=de" href="#foofoobar" class="active">Test<span class="tab-item-count">8</span></a></li>
        <li>
        <li>
        <li>
        <li>
          .
          .
          .
    </ul>
```

The general idea was this:

1. Get ul
2. Iterate through every li item
3. Get 'a' using .children()
4. Invoke href and compare to a string

I tried to iterate through the list and check the hrefs using several approaches. This is my latest attempt:

```js
describe('check hrefs', () => {
    it('check hrefs', () => {

        cy.login()
        cy.visit('url3')
        cy.get('tbody > :nth-child(1) > .col-id-large').click({force: true})
        cy.get('#clientinfotabs > ul')
            .each(($el) => {
                cy.get($el).children().invoke('attr','href').should('not.include','creditcheck');
            })
    })
})
```

That's what Cypress returns when I run this script:

```js
AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 10000ms: object tested must be an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset, but undefined given
cypress/integration/test2.spec.js:10:62
   8 |         cy.get('#clientinfotabs > ul')
   9 |             .each(($el) => {
> 10 |                 cy.get($el).children().invoke('attr','href').should('not.include','creditcheck');
     |                                                              ^
  11 |             })
  12 |     })
  13 | })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are really close. Instead of `cy.get()` you have to use `cy.wrap()`. And also you can directly loop over li using the selector `#clientinfotabs > ul > li`.

```js
describe('check hrefs', () => {
  it('check hrefs', () => {
    cy.login()
    cy.visit('url3')
    cy.get('tbody > :nth-child(1) > .col-id-large').click({force: true})
    cy.get('#clientinfotabs > ul >li').each(($el) => {
      cy.wrap($el).invoke('attr', 'href').should('not.include', 'creditcheck')
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Amazing! This works exactly as I was hoping! Thank you very much.

Need to look into cy.wrap() now. And make sure I don't forget something in the selector like 'li' here.